# How to remove attached scripts files on deleting add-on?

Tags: python, add-on

My addon is constituted by two files scripts. 
when I push the 'Remove' button , one file stay on the addons folder.

[image]

How can I tell blender remove the two python files from the addons directory?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean... You want blender to delete the python files from the addons directory? Isn't this already what happens?

Comment: @gandalf3 yes, delete the python files from the addons directory. How can I do this ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because is appears to be a misunderstanding of Python modules. If your addon is properly set-up as directory with your script files incl. a `__init__.py`, a click on *Remove* should delete the entire folder.

Comment: @CoDEmanX ok thanks for this suggestion (I did not know it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my `__init__.py` file

I put this:

```
if "bpy" in locals():
    import imp
    imp.reload(myScript)
```

and everything works fine :)